# Spring 2.5 managed servlets: howto?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, dependency-injection

Correct me if anything is wrong.

As I understand, all Spring functionality, namely DI works when beans are got thru

Spring Context, ie getBean() method.

Otherwise, none can work, even if my method is marked @Transactional and I will

create the owning class with a new operator, no transaction management will be provided.

I use Tomcat 6 as a servlet container.

**So, my question is: how to make Servlet methods managed by Spring framework.**

The issue here is that I use a framework, and its servlets extend the functionality of

basic java Servlets, so they have more methods. Still, web.xml is present in an app as usual.

The thing is that I do not control the servlets creation flow, I can only override a few methods

of each servlet, the flow is basically written down in some xml file, but I control this process

using a graphical gui.

So, basically, I only add some code to a few methods of each Servlet.

How to make those methods managed by Spring framework? The basic thing I need to do is

making these methods transactional (@Transactional).

comment to Bozho:

*@Bozho Let's see. 
In these servlets' methods I work with framework capabilities, let's say special variables that are got and saved in the current session. 
And what is needed, is looping through those framework-based collections while saving some values in a database. 
**What you suggest is introducing a new very complex object, so that it could be passed to a service layer.** (Service layer will not know anything about framework, its classes and objects kept in current Session! 
First, we "wrap" framework based collections to such a object, so copy everything into it. 
Then, again, the Service layer method should either save changes in a database or, worse case, return a new complex object so that Servlet framework method could update framework variables depending on the result of Service layer method execution. 
It is a workaround but do you think it is a good idea?*

Answer (score 2):

You can also define your servlets directly in the Spring application context. You'll need a "proxy" servlet registered in `web.xml` and delegating to the servlet instance which is configured as bean in the `applicationContext.xml`. Proxy servlet is configured with the name of the target servlet bean, it discovers this bean via `WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext().getBean(...)` and delegates all the processing to the target servlet. In this case an instance of your servlet is completely managed by Spring.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest restructuring your code - making servlet methods transactional is not a good thing to do. Put the transactional logic in a separate, service class, and either

- obtain these spring-managed classes by `WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext().getBean(..)` or
- in your servlet `init()` method obtain the `ApplicationContext` with the above method and call `appCtx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this)`. This way you can inject the transactional classes in your servlet as if it was spring-managed.

Now, you can do all this, but it is definitely not a beautiful way to go. I'd suggest using Spring MVC or any other MVC framework (which support spring integration of its components)

If this is all not possible, as a last resort I think you can use `@Configurable` (on your servlets) with a `<context:load-time-weaver/>`.

Comment: @Bozho Please see my comment. I also thought about what you suggested, but as I describe the situation, it is not the most beautiful workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look how Spring proxy filters:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.web/3.0.2/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.java

In theory you could easily make the same sort of proxy for servlets and DispatcherServlet is sort of a proxy.