# @Inject only working for POJOs created by CDI container?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, cdi

I just want to confirm that I fully understood the prerequisites for CDI to work. If I have a class A:

```
public class A {
    @Inject private B b;
}
```

Now when I instantiate this class using:

```
A a = new A();
```

In that case, A.b will be null.

But if I define in another class a member:

```
@Inject A a;
```

and later use a, a.b will be correctly populated?

Does CDI only work if the class requiring an injection was also created by CDI container? Or what am I missing if injections turn out to be null while creating a POJO using ordinary instantiation with new (yes, I got beans.xml in place)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While others have stated correctly that for the most part DI containers will not inject dependencies into bean that they did not instantiate this is not entirely true.

Spring has a wonderful feature that will autowire the bean when you create it using `new A()`.
You just have to use [AspectJ and mark your bean with the `@Configurable` annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch07s08.html).

```
@Configurable
public class A {
    @Inject private B b;
}
```

Its actually kind of an awesome feature cause you can do Active Record style POJO's while still honoring your DI (its in fact how Spring Roo does it).

You should also know that with Spring you can autowire a bean programmatically after its been instantiated with the [AutowireCapableBeanFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html). This is how it typically autowires JUnit Test Case Classes because JUnit creates the test case classes.

**Yes Spring is not CDI** but in theory you could write your own `@Configurable` for CDI or there is probably a CDI way of doing the above.

That being said the above is sort of a sophisticated feature (and kind of a hack) and as @JanGroth mentioned understaning the [lifecycle bean management of the container](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html) is critical whether its CDI, Spring, Guice etc.

Comment: Hm, the OP asked about CDI and the finally accepted answer describes a Spring features. Weired. :)

Comment: @jangroth I didn't think I was going to be marked correct. I just put my answer in case someone wanted to do DI with `new *()` ... I also kind of guessed that he really wanted that but maybe I just confused him more. You can always -1 my post :)

Comment: No worries mate, I'm more then happy to +1 you for bringing up this interesting aspect :)

Comment: The thing is that almost all answer were correct. So I chose the one, which gave me most insights.

Answer (score 10):

> Does CDI only work if the class requiring an injection was also
>   created by CDI container?

Yes, that's pretty much it. The lifecycle of a `ManagedBean` is controlled by the container and should never be instantiated with the `new` keyword (BTW: the same is true for EJBs & Spring beans). If you need to create a new ManagedBean you will probably want to use a [producer method](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/beanscdi.html#d0e948).

Comment: Ah, now I start to understand why there are producer methods.

Comment: That is not entirely true that new will not inject. You can make `new` inject with spring: [See Spring's @Configurable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch07s08.html)

Comment: I was hoping to get around spring and stick to pure JEE6 for CDI. But I think CDI is quiet limited. For example, if I have a servlet context, I can't inject anything managed by CDI as the servlet class doesn't get created by CDI container. I guess that's where Spring would be useful.

Comment: I agree. I have tried many of the others like Guice and I always always come back to Spring. Spring just has so many useful things like its JDBCTemplate (I know its unrelated but another example of useful stuff it comes with). And it supports `@Transaction` better than anything else.

Comment: @Sebi Speaking of servlet container things managed by Spring have a look at `org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy`. Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635406/spring-2-5-managed-servlets-howto

Comment: I now looked up references to beans in places where I can't inject them by using CDI bean manager as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4934139/324531

Comment: @sebi - In regards to your comment about CDI and servlet containers. Your understanding is incorrect. You can happily Inject a CDI bean into a servlet w/JavaEE6. A servlet, or servlet filter is a 'managed' object to the CDI container. This also applies to JAX-RS / Jersey resources so you can inject into them as well. You can also inject an EJB into a servlet as well.

Comment: @AdamGreen - From my understanding the OP is (was) completely unaware of the container taking over responsibility for a bean's lifecycle. That's why I still think that `new Foo()` is not a good idea for a hello world attempt with dependency injection - even though most containers (including CDI) offer ways to work around this limitation.

Comment: @jangroth I mostly agree. I was just offering a pedantic correction that somehow got accepted as the correct answer. As I said in my answer you (and others) are correct :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use `BeanProvider.injectFields(myObject);` from [Apache DeltaSpike](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/core.html#BeanProvider).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, @Inject works only inside a container because it is done using interceptors on method calls. When the container creates a bean it wrappes it in interceptors which perform injection, and in the case of instantiation using **new** no interceptors will be called during bean method invocation, and there will be no injection.

Comment: Does injection happen in interceptors? Or does it happen when the container creates the bean? I would imagine it's the latter. If you're using constructor injection, it must be the latter.

Comment: No, @Inject does not work with interceptors - it works with proxies (mainly for performance reasons). Check out the excellent documentation for [Weld](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/) to get the full picture.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the conditions needed for a class to be a managed bean (and hence, for the @Inject annotation to work on its fields/methods):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjfzi.html