# Pass runtime arguments to Object containing Injections

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

**Context:**

Based on an XML my Java EE application receives, I want to make a new AreeConfiguration object in which Injection of 3 objects happens. The selection of a correct Instance<> happens based on information in this XML. Therefore, I am passing around information from this XML.

I have a datastructure which should be filled with these AreeConfiguration objects at runtime:

```
private HashMap<Integer, AreeConfiguration> configurations = new HashMap<Integer, AreeConfiguration>();

public void parseNewConfiguration(Element el) throws InvalidDescriptorException {
    if(!isValidConfiguration(el)) throw new InvalidDescriptorException();

    int key = getUniqueKey();

    AreeConfiguration cfg = new AreeConfiguration(key, el);       
    configurations.put(key, cfg);
}
```

My AreeConfiguration object should (ideally) be constructed with the essential XML information and Inject some objects. Later, I want to use the information from the XML to pick the right Instance<>.

```
public class AreeConfiguration {

@Inject
private Instance<AreeInput> ais;
private AreeInput ai;

@Inject
private Instance<AreeReasoner> ars;
private AreeReasoner ar;

@Inject
private Instance<AreeOutput> aos;
private AreeOutput ao;

AreeConfiguration(int key, Element el) throws InvalidDescriptorException {
    ...
}   

@PostConstruct
public void chooseComponents(){     
    ai = chooseInput();
    ar = chooseReasoner();
    ao = chooseOutput();
}
```

**What I have found and tried:**

Through research (here at Stack Overflow), I now understand that CDI does not Inject in objects that have been created with `new Object()`. The code displayed above, never enters `chooseComponents()`.

When I want to try using an @Producer, I annotate `parseNewConfiguration(Element el)` with `@Producer` and add an `@New AreeConfiguration cfg` argument. However, then I cannot pass the `Element el` too, which is unfortunate because it contains the essential XML information.

Please ask additional questions if I did not explain myself thoroughly. I am looking for a way to accomplish the above using CDI.

Additionally, how 'clean' is the solution proposed in the answer of this question: [@Inject only working for POJOs created by CDI container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080317/inject-only-working-for-pojos-created-by-cdi-container)

Comment: Hi, how is the XML sent to the server? Is this some kind of REST API?

Comment: Yes: @PUT
    @Path("/put")
    @Consumes("application/xml") public Response putXml(String content) is where the XML enters the server, for now.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what's in this XML document? Does it use IDs to load data in to these other objects?  My initial thought is to veto the default installed versions of these objects and replace with a set of producer methods in your CDI enabled REST resource.

Comment: The XML file defines criteria for selection of the Injected object in an Instance<> collection. Such criteria are: classnames and version information. This XML is essential in that sense that after a bunch of Instance<Object> Injections have happened, I can use the XML information to pick the bean my client really needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, dynamic injections only need to take place after a client's call. Therefore, I am now simply injecting what I need in my WebService. When a client calls the WebService, an injection automatically takes place.

```
@Path("newconfiguration")
@RequestScoped
public class NewConfigurationResource {

@Context
private UriInfo context;

@Inject
private AreeConfiguration injConfig;

public NewConfigurationResource() { }

@POST
@Path("post")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response postJson() {
    ...
    doSomething(injConfig);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To perform injection into instances that were not created by a CDI container, and you have access to the BeanManager, then you can do something like:

```
// Create a creational context from the BeanManager
CreationalContext creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);

// Create an injection target with the Type of the instance we need to inject into
InjectionTarget injectionTarget = beanManager.createInjectionTarget(beanManager.createAnnotatedType(instance.getClass()));

// Perform injection into the instance
injectionTarget.inject(instance, creationalContext);

// Call PostConstruct on instance
injectionTarget.postConstruct(instance);
```

An example of a class that can be used to do all the work is at: http://seamframework.org/Documentation/HowDoIDoNoncontextualInjectionForAThirdpartyFramework.

Answer (score 0):

You are generally correct, at most you can pass in some finite data types to CDI to create objects - namely primitives, static types, Strings, enums in to your qualifiers.  This is a limitation of annotations.  One thing I don't quite understand with your structure is why the client is passing all of this to you.  This makes your code much more fragile and the client and server more tightly coupled.  Couldn't you pass around some ID that represented a certain configuration? You still have the issue of not being able to pass around an XML element.  You could pass around a string and have that available in a producer method's InjectionPoint.

Comment: Thanks John. The server contains 3 big interfaces: an input processor, a component that does reasoning and an output preparer. The idea is that *any* client can tell the server (via XML) which implementations of these 3 interfaces it needs to get something done. In theory, there are infinite combinations of these 3 interfaces and thus infinite AreeConfigurations. This is part of research, not production code. Somewhat fragile code is okay.