# Configuring Entity properties

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee

In a Java EE project, I've found a recurrent solution for configuring the application that consists on the use of `@Injection` of primitives/Strings on managed beans, avoiding external dependencies on that way.

What about `@Entity`? Is there some "good practice code" for configuring entities using only Java EE (no Spring)?

Comment: What's the meaning of *configuring entities*?

Comment: In my case, a concrete example is to tell an `@Entity` externally which Hash algorithm has to use to hash a user password, or the required minimum password length.

Comment: Shouldn't it belong to your service layer? I don't think it's related to persistence.

Comment: The service knowing something about data hashing and storage?

Answer (score 0):

CDI does not support injection into objects that are not created by the CDI container (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080317/inject-only-working-for-pojos-created-by-cdi-container)). Since entities are created by JPA provider when they are loaded from the DB, CDI would obviously not work.

So, in plain Java EE world your only options are to move the logic depending on the injected resources out of the entities, or to access the resources via static methods from within the entities. Keep in mind the increased complexity when testing the entities if static state/methods are used.